# Как определить устройство, магнитола или простая мобилка?

Tags: android

Как определить устройство, магнитола или простая мобилка?

Comment: а что понимается под словом `магнитола`?

Comment: @ermak0ff, Трудно в гугл ввести это слово и глянуть?, сразу видно что у вас даже машины нет, точнее сказать что вы даже в машине не разу не были

Comment: очень конечно остроумно с Вашей стороны по поводу машины, но относительно слова `магнитола` к сожалению так и не понял Ваш деревенский слэнг, как можно разделять телефоны на `простая мобилка` и `магнитола`...или Вы Ильнар когда на коне едите, под `магнитолой` понимаете устройство с громким динамиком, прошу разъяснить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if(telephonyManager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE)
     //это не телефон
else
     //это телефон
```

**Update:**

Можно определять и более продвинутые свойства через `PackageManager`:

```
PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();

if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT))
    //есть датчик отпечатка пальцев
else
    //нет сенсора отпечатка пальцев
```

Полный список фич [здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

Comment: Ок, спасибо, а то я вначале по разрешениям определял, а после оказывается что есть такие планшеты, вот и не знал